# Login form not working correctly while throttling

Tags: php, sql, function, return-value, throttling

I have the below login authentication code, I added some functionalities like throttling etc.

Now, my function for throttling is working, the problems are:

1- The function locks the user for a period of time, but it doesn't actually happen.

2- If problem 1 is fixed, then how should I implement the authentication in a way that when the lockout time is passed and finished, the user will be allowed to log in and not sooner.

My Code is:

```
            <?php 

                //function to throttle:

                function check(PDO $muc){
                    function get_multiple_rows($getfailed) {
                        $rows = array();
                        while($row = $getfailed->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $rows[] = $row;
                        }
                        return $rows;
                    }
                    $throttle = array(1 => 10, 5 => 20, 30 => 30);  
                    if ($getfailed = $muc->query("SELECT MAX(attempted) AS attempted FROM failed_logins")){
                        $rows = get_multiple_rows($getfailed);
                        $getfailed->closeCursor();
                        $latest_attempt = (int) date('U', strtotime($rows[0]['attempted'])); 
                        if ($getfailed = $muc->query("SELECT COUNT(1) AS failed FROM failed_logins WHERE attempted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute)")){
                            $rows = get_multiple_rows($getfailed);
                            $getfailed->closeCursor();
                            $failed_attempts = (int) $rows[0]['failed'];
                            krsort($throttle);
                                foreach ($throttle as $attempts => $delay){
                                if ($failed_attempts > $attempts) {
                                    $remaining_delay = (time() - $latest_attempt) - $delay;
                                    if ($remaining_delay < 0){
                                        echo "remaining time until next try".abs($remaining_delay); 
                                    }
                                    break;  
                                    return true;                                        
                                }else{
                                    return false;   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }       
                }

                //The code for authentication:
                //if function returns false or remaining time is zero let user login
                if(check($muc) == false || $remaining_delay == 0){
                    $much = $muc->query('SELECT * from users_enc WHERE name=name');
                    $much->bindParam(1, $name);
                    $much->bindParam(2, $password);
                    $much->execute();
                    $much->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    while($row = $much->fetch()) {  
                        $dbname = $row['Name'];
                        $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
                    }
                    if($_POST['name']==$dbname){
                        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $dbpassword)){
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['Name'] = $_POST['name'];
                            $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['password'];
                            $successq = $muc->query("DELETE FROM failed_logins WHERE name = '".$_SESSION['Name']."'");
                            $successq->execute();
                            echo"<a href='../onlinestore.php' style='color:green;padding:10px;background-color:rgba(240,255,240,0.5);border:1px solid green;border-radius:5px;'>You can enter here</a><br /><br />";
                        }else{
                            echo $err4;
                            include("throttle.php");
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo $err3;
                        include("throttle.php");
                        $stmt = $muc->prepare('SELECT Name from failed_logins WHERE name=:name');
                        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        if($stmt->rowCount() > 100){
                            $overdose = $muc->query("DELETE FROM failed_logins WHERE name = name");
                            $overdose->execute();
                        }
                    }
                }   
            ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to be far to complicated, most of this is totally unnecessary, and you are doing things in the wrong order. It can all be done with the SESSION rather than all this database stuff. Describe what you want to do to someone that cannot possibly understand the concept. That will help you boil this process down to its simplest ( and it is simple) process.

Comment: First of all, don't set `$_SESSION['Name'] = $_POST['name']; $_SESSION['Password'] = $_POST['password'];` before you get successful authentication. you can move it after you got record from DB. That way you don't have to destroy them.

Comment: You are also `prepare`ing a statement with no parameters and then trying to `bindParam`eters to that statement. Surely that should throw an error!

Comment: You can keep the `failedLogins` counter in the session, you dont need a database for that

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks, I will get to that now

Comment: I call it the "Cardboard Analyst" it does not even have to be a real person

Comment: You might also want to lookup `captcha`

Comment: @MuhammadKashifAbbasi, thank you very much, got rid of that problem I will edit my question accordingly

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks a lot, need to understand a lot yet, "Cardboard Analyst" is it a tool? I have taken captcha into account for the future

Comment: @RiggsFolly, also could you describe more about the bind param part?

Comment: You would be better advised to [Have a look at the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, OK Thank you for your consideration and analysis, much appreciated